# Flexible and "Squishable" Tubing for Peristaltic Pump Model in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I have made a rough model in solidworks of a peristaltic pump we purchased in my lab. There are no moving parts. Screenshots shown below. **Is it possible to make assemblies with the three sets of tubing (1/4", 5/16", 3/8" ID with 3/32" wall thickness) bent and squashed around the rotor similar to what is shown in 4?**

The lengths of tubing are all roughly 4.5 inches long (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1gV.png)) and I think they are made of viton. The straight length between the middle of each fitting is 107 mm (4.21 in) so there seems to be only about 0.3 in of tubing left to go over the rotors. The tubing is also compressed by a door which has an inner radius of about 33.3 mm (1.31 in) and is offset from main shaft of the motor by 5.36 mm (0.211 in) when closed. The rotors themselves are 14.5 mm (0.571 in) in diameter, and positioned 17 mm (0.669 in) radially from the center of the main shaft.

*Please let me know if this is possible, or if any other information is needed.*

1. **Screenshot of Model**

I didn't include the tubing here, but that is in the drawing I made below with different views of the pump.

[image: Screenshot 1]

2. **Drawing of Model**

I made these measurements myself, so it's not perfectly accurate but I compared the model with the actual pump and it's close enough for my purposes.

[image: Screenshot 2]

3. **Drawings from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XF6KK3T)**

[image: Amazon Sketch]

4. **Images from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XF6KK3T)**

[image: Amazon Image]
[image: Amazon Tubing]

Comment: If there are no moving parts then what do the rotors do with the main shaft connected to the motor?

Comment: Are you looking for a static model of it in a squished state, or something that will update dynamically e.g. during a motion study?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a static model in the "squished state". There was no need to build the entire motor in solidworks, so I just picked an arbitrary position for the drive shaft and connected the rotors to it in that position.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need to some sort of lofting operation between circles and eclipses. But really, since you don't need to manufacturer a squished tube, it probably just isn't worth modeling.